# Spine.js & rails - Spine.js doesn't use plural form of model name for the routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, spine.js

I am following the guide of integrating `Spine.js` with `Rails 3`.

I created a model `Activity` and follow the [spine.js guide](http://spinejs.com/docs/rails) to try it out. When I tried to create an activity I got this error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/activitys 404 (Not Found)
```

Clearly it's not pluralize the model name for the route, is it fixable from spine.js side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the model's endpoint URL in Spine if the URL Spine guessed is not the correct one. Put the following inside your `activity.js.coffee` file:

```
    class App.Activity extends Spine.Model
        @url: '/activities'
```

That should make Spine hit the proper endpoint.

Comment: Thanks @fholgado, but I found it could not come at the first line of the class. I edited your answer.